# How to prove the roots of cosine is dense or sparse when a tend to infinity?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

So I am a bit surprised that there isn't a question on this. Recall the first time when you came across the cosine function $\cos (ax)$ as $a \to \infty$ graphically, it intersect the x axis more and more frequently, result in the limit to diverge

Now, more familiar with the different kinds of infinite sets, I am actually wondering whether the roots are dense as $a\to \infty$. It seems that plugging in any $a$ the position of the roots can be any real number, and the roots are regularly spaced by some nonzero intervals for any $a$, thus it seems as $a \to \infty$ there is never a case that the roots will be dense.

How to approach this problem?

Comment: Warning: The limit of a sequence of sets isn't always so easy to get a grip on.

Comment: For any finite $a$, the roots will not be dense, though one can choose $a$ so that roots are arbitrarily close together (there will be something on the order of $a$ roots between $0$ and $2\pi$).  In this sense, the roots become dense (I suppose).  On the other hand, you might really be trying to compute $\lim_{a\to\infty} R_a$, where $$R_a := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \cos(ax) = 0 \}. $$  Of course, if that is your goal, then you need to define the sense in which you are taking this limit.

Comment: For fixed $a$, the roots will be of the form $\frac{1}{a}(\pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)$ for some integer $n$ which is a nowhere dense set. I'm not sure how to make the jump to a limit of these sets though. lim sup/inf don't quite work IMO because they have behavior that doesn't match what you want.

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$ and any real $\beta$ there is a positive number $\gamma$ such that if $a>\gamma$ then $\cos ax$ has a zero within $\epsilon$ of $\beta$.

Comment: So, is that what you meant by *dense*, Secret?

Comment: I think so, I am thinking more about dense in reals in the topological sense, which means the limit set L is dense in reals if all points in L are either in reals or has a limit point in the reals, which your epsilon comment seemed to suggests, though I still not sure whether a sequence of nowhere dense sets (this will result for any finite a) can actually converge to that

Comment: You keep referring to a limit set $L$. As several of us have pointed out, the limit of a sequence of sets is a tricky concept, and maybe it's not what you really want. I'm pointing to something that may be what you really need; that once $a$ is large enough your set will contain points arbitrarily close to every real number.

Comment: yeah I think that epsilon method may be close enough to what I have in mind. It agrees with the topological sense of being dense in the reals as well. You may be able to make that into an answer so I can accept it

Comment: An answer it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots are dense, in the following interpretation of the word.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a real number $r=r_{\epsilon}$ such that if $a>r$ then given any real number $\beta$, $\cos ax$ has a zero within $\epsilon$ of $\beta$.